A two-dimensional version of Dirichlet's function
Problem: Let $D=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and consider the function $f\colon D\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=0$, if $x\in \mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ and $1$ otherwise. Investigate the existence of the Riemann-integral $$\iint_D f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y.$$
Solution: Does this just follow the same idea as the $1$-dimensional analogue, or am I missing something? That is, the (Riemann-)integral does not exist.

It is pretty much the same, thanks to the density of $\mathbb{Q}$.
Partition $D$ into a collection of rectangles $I_k$, and then the upper/lower Darboux sums
$$\begin{align*}
U(\{I_k\},f) &:= \sum_k \left[ \sup_{(x,y) \in I_k} f(x,y) \right] \operatorname{area}(I_k)\\
L(\{I_k\},f) &:= \sum_k \left[ \inf_{(x,y) \in I_k} f(x,y) \right] \operatorname{area}(I_k)
\end{align*}$$
cannot always be made to be within a $\varepsilon$ of each other. Define
$$
\text{for $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ } \pi(S) := \{ x \mid (x,y) \in S \}
$$
Then $\pi(I_k)$ always has an interval of positive length, hence containing a rational; hence the upper sum is always $1$ and the lower sum is always $0$.
